# Tiene "realización" el significado de comprensión en Español?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, inglés, préstamo-lingüístico, false-friend

Según la RAE , realización es [Realización](https://dle.rae.es/?w=realizaci%C3%B3n)

> Acción y efecto de realizar o realizarse.

y [realizar](https://dle.rae.es/realizar?m=form)

> 1. tr. Efectuar, llevar a cabo algo o ejecutar una acción. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. tr. Dirigir la ejecución de una película o de un programa televisivo.
> 3. tr. Com. Vender, convertir en dinero mercaderías u otros bienes. U. más comúnmente hablando de la venta a bajo precio para reducirlos
>      pronto a dinero.
> 4. prnl. Sentirse satisfecho por haber logrado cumplir aquello a lo que se aspiraba.

Según Google, otras definiciones de [realización](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=dfp9XqzeBJHL5OUPmqy0qAE&q=realizaci%C3%B3n&oq=realizaci%C3%B3n) derivada de *realizar*.

Sin embargo, en Inglés la palabra equivalente "realization", también tiene el significado de "comprensión". Yo he escuchado esta palabra ser usada de la misma forma en Español, pero no sé si de forma correcta o no. Creo que esto ya lo han discutido si una palabra que no figura en la RAE o en la RAE con determinado significado, si su significado es válido o no (si no existe ninguna referencia cualquiera le podría dar cualquier significado a cualquier palabra) pero al menos,

¿existe en algún diccionario conocido con este significado en Español?

¿Existe algún parámetro que determine que pueda o sea conveniente usarla o no en Español de esta manera?

Comment: En mi opinión y según las referencias que citas no. Nunca he oído a alguien que luego de escuchar una explicación diga "ahora lo realizo". Siempre decimos "ahora lo entiendo/comprendo". Ni siquiera como anglicismo funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En los Estados Unidos, por influencia del cognado inglés *realise*, sí realizar tiene este significado, pero como nota la entrada es poco usado:

> [**realizar.**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=realizar) <sub>(Del ingl. *to realize*).</sub>
>   ...
>   II. 1.  tr. *EU*, Pa. p.u. Comprender, darse cuenta.